# R - Extract - transform - replace subsets of a vector: alternative to loop?

Tags: r, loops, replace

I need to convert a numeric vector `y` to a factor (using `cut2{Hmisc}`), but I want to do so separately for each value of another vector `x`.

For now I am using a `for` loop:

```
x <- c(1,3,2,3,3,1,2,2,1,3,1,3,2,2,1)
y <- abs(rnorm(15))
yf <-NULL
for (i in 1:3) {
yf[x==i]<-cut2(y[x==i],g=2) 
}
```

I am having trouble finding a solution that does not involve a loop. Could anyone suggest a solution that uses `apply` or, even better, a vectorized solution? Any insight would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
My question boils down to: is there an easy way to apply a function to a same vector multiple times, but sequentially, for different values of an argument (that here defines groups of data). In my case the function would be:

```
function(i) {
yf[x==i]<-cut2(y[x==i],g=2) 
}
```

`ave` does work, but is there any other simple solution?

Comment: What's your intended output for these example data?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. I want to end up with an integer vector `yf` of same lengh as `y`. When using `by` or `tapply`, I end up with several subvectors, but then I need to assign them to a `yf` vector of    the same length as `y`. This is the step where I have trouble not using a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ave`:

```
ave(y, x, FUN = function(i) cut2(i, g = 2))
```